# .NET Block Diagram Component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, diagramming

I'm looking for an affordable diagramming component for a C#/.NET (WinForms) application that will let users create diagrams like this one:

[image]

What would you recommend to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MS Automatic Graph layout](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/)
[yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesdotnet_about.html) looks great, but kinda expensive
[mindfusion](http://www.mindfusion.eu/gallery-net.html) has something for winforms too